# adicionar ao array depois do loop

Tags: php, array, loop

Eu tenho alguns loops no meu php e quero obter um array assim:

```
Array ( [nome1] => valor [nome2] => valor )
```

dentro de um loop eu tentei : `$array_dos_pagamentos[nome] = $variavelnome;`
e noutro  loop `$array_dos_pagamentos[valor] = $variavelvalor;`

o problema é que o sai `Array ( [nome] => Susana laginha, [valor] => 84 )` 
ou seja apenas um registo.. se eu fizer :

```
$array_dos_pagamentos[]=$variavelnome;
$array_dos_pagamentos[]=$variavelvalor;
```

sai

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Beatriz grade 
        [1] => 15 
        [2] => Promotores 
        [3] => 40 
        [4] => Susana laginha 
        [5] => 84 
)
```

Comment: tente `$array_dos_pagamentos = array('nome' => $variavelnome, 'valor' => $variavelvalor);`

Comment: lembrando que se a pergunta respondeu sua dúvida, marque a questão como respondida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que acontece no seu caso é que você está gravando tudo sempre no mesmo índice associativo do array.

Quando você grava:

```
$array_dos_pagamentos["nome"] = $variavel_qualquer;
```

Isso significa que o índice "nome" do array_dos_pagamentos recebe o valor de variavel_qualquer. A segunda vez que o loop roda ele substitui o que há dentro de "nome" por uma nova variavel_qualquer.

Para solucionar o seu problema, você precisa associar o nome ao índice do seu array. Desse Jeito:

```
$array_dos_pagamentos[$variavelnome] = $variavelvalor;
```

Mas Cuidado! Se houverem dois nomes iguais o valor do primeiro será substituído pelo valor do segundo.